# How to directly access .NET Reflector from VS2008

Tags: visual-studio-2008, add-in, reflector, .net-reflector

I'm sure this is very simple, but I'm having some trouble.  I want to be able to disassemble a class in reflector directly from VS2008.

**Background:** At one point I had Visual Studio 2008 working such that all I had to do was right click+"Open in .NET Reflector" to view the source of anything.  One day it went away.  I have downloaded ManagedAddins, but I must be doing something wrong, because when I try to integrate it, the source code for the reflector add in solution opens.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://www.testdriven.net/ - This has the feature and all I had to do was download and install.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have .NET Reflector Pro ? I believe the functionality you are talking about is only in Pro Version. In standard free version, it is available for 14 days trial.

Comment: It's not just in the Pro version, it's in Standard as well.

Answer (score 0):

The Visual Studio add-in is available in Standard as well as Pro. Not sure why it has got disabled. To make sure that it's enabled, open Reflector, then go to Tools->Integration Options, and select the appropriate Visual Studio Integration checkbox.

Comment: Sorry, been away for the holidays.  I will try this out and if it works, I will select your answer.